# Why my app stops when firebase throws an exception?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm using the firebase auth plugin for flutter, and when I type an user that doesn't exists, it throws a Platform exception.
[image: Code]

Ok.. but unless i click continue(f5)
[image: Continue]
the app is stopped. When I continue, the app works fine an show the snackbar.

Am I doing something wrong? Should i use catchError? (Got the same issue)

I dont really know if this is intended behaviour.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: add a try/catch block. Your app throws an unhandled exception. Why it should continue?

Comment: hi @RubensMelo, I have a try catch.

Comment: when you tap go over, it works ?

Comment: yes it does @RubensMelo

Answer (score 1):

Check your Visual Studio Code breakpoint settings as shown in the image here. You probably have 'All exceptions' checked.
[image: Visual Studio Code screenshot]

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer. I have all exceptions unchecked and uncaught checked.

Comment: hmm, what happens when you uncheck Uncaught exceptions? Also, are you running the latest version of VSC? If none of the above work, I'm at a lost to why this is occurring as it shouldn't. Try turning it off an on again =/

Comment: If I uncheck Uncaught exceptions, the app works normally. The exception is thrown into the debug console. I do have the latest versión of VSCode. It's really weird, i also thought that it should only appears if "all exceptions" was checked and not the other way around.

Comment: Hi, did you figure out the issue?

Comment: hi @F-1 , not at all. It keeps happening.